# Azure Activity Log

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-log-analytics

I want to monitor who made a change in rbac assignment, I created powershell script for collection data from Azure Activity Log. I used below piece of code. Using this solution I am able to get items like:
caller - user who made a role assignment change,
timestamp,
Resource name - on this resource assignment change has been provided,
action type - write or delete

In Activity Log panel in Azure portal, in Summary portal (Message: shared with "user info"), I can see name of a user who has been granted permissions/assignment to the resource, but using my powershell script I am not able to catch this information, is there any method to get this info?

```
Get-AzureRmLog -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) | 
Where-Object {$_.Authorization.Action -like 
'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/*'} |
Select-Object @{N="Caller";E={$_.Caller}}, 
@{N="Resource";E={$_.Authorization.Scope}}, 
@{N="Action";E={Split-Path $_.Authorization.action -leaf}},
EventTimestamp
```

script output:

```
Caller         : username@xxx.com
Resource   :/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/Powershell/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xx/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/xxxx
Action         : write
EventTimestamp : 8/29/2019 10:12:31 AM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement of fetching the user name to whom the RBAC role is assigned is currently not supported using Az PowerShell cmdlet [Get-AzLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azlog?view=azps-2.6.0) or [Get-AzureRmLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/get-azurermlog?view=azurermps-6.13.0).

However, we can accomplish your requirement by leveraging Azure REST API for [Activity Logs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activitylogs/list) and Az PowerShell cmdlet [Get-AzureADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0).

In this way as we are depending on Azure REST API for [Activity Logs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activitylogs/list) (but looks like you want PowerShell way of accomplishing the requirement) so call the REST API in PowerShell as something shown below.

```
    $request = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2015-04-01&`$filter={$filter}"
    $auth = "eyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    $authHeader = @{
    'Content-Type'='application/json'
    'Accept'='application/json'
    'Authorization'= "Bearer $auth"
    }
    $Output = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $request -Headers $authHeader -Method GET -Body $Body
    $ActivityLogsFinalOutput = $Output.Value
```

Develop your PowerShell code to get "PrincipalId" (which is under "properties") from the output of your Azure REST API for [Activity Logs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activitylogs/list) call. The fetched "PrincipalId" is the ObjectID of the user whom you want to get ultimately.

Now leverage Az PowerShell cmdlet [Get-AzureADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0) and have your command something like shown below.

```
(Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID "<PrincipalID>").DisplayName
```

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!

**UPDATE:**

Please find PowerShell way of fetching auth token (i.e., $auth) that needs to be used in above REST API call.

```
$ClientID       = "<ClientID>" #ApplicationID
$ClientSecret   = "<ClientSecret>"  #key from Application
$tennantid      = "<TennantID>"

$TokenEndpoint = {https://login.windows.net/{0}/oauth2/token} -f $tennantid 
$ARMResource = "https://management.core.windows.net/";

$Body1 = @{
        'resource'= $ARMResource
        'client_id' = $ClientID
        'grant_type' = 'client_credentials'
        'client_secret' = $ClientSecret
}

$params = @{
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    Headers = @{'accept'='application/json'}
    Body = $Body1
    Method = 'Post'
    URI = $TokenEndpoint
}

$token = Invoke-RestMethod @params
$token | select access_token, @{L='Expires';E={[timezone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(([datetime]'1/1/1970').AddSeconds($_.expires_on))}} | fl *
```

I see [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Easily-obtain-AccessToken-3ba6e593) new way as well but I didn't get chance to test this out. If interested, you may alternatively try this or go with above approach.

**UPDATE2:**

```
$ActivityLogsFinalOutput| %{
    if(($_.properties.responseBody) -like "*principalId*"){
        $SplittedPrincipalID = $_.properties.responseBody -split "PrincipalID"
        $SplittedComma = $SplittedPrincipalID[1] -split ","
        $SplittedDoubleQuote = $SplittedComma[0] -split "`""
        $PrincipalID = $SplittedDoubleQuote[2]
        #Continue code for getting Azure AD User using above fetched $PrincipalID
        #...
        #...
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably Your answer is ok, but I am still getting error message --> "Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"The access token is invalid."}". I have created new PAT, with full access, and tried to run the script few times and facing the same issue. Some time ago I had similar problem, and after some time problem has been resolved, I regenerate my PAT few times, maybe this is a solution, will try to run a script in 2 hours again with a new PAT key.

Comment: I think token i AM using is incorrect, do You know how can i get token i can use with invoke-restmethod?

Comment: Yes, I know. Updated the above answer with the required information accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for Your sulotion, but explain where can i find $ClientID, $ClientSecret? This is a powershell script querring Azure Activity logs.

Comment: Sure. ClientID, ClientSecret are Azure AD Application's (Service Principal) App ID and Password respectively. You may need to generate one initially once using [New-AzADServicePrincipal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Az.Resources/New-AzADServicePrincipal?view=azps-2.6.0) to get these. For more info, refer [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azps-2.6.0) doc. Alternatively [az ad sp create-for-rbac](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create-for-rbac) is Az CLI way.

Comment: I have $auth, I used .ps1 script from the link You proposed. I used $filter="eventTimestamp ge '2019-08-16T04:36:37.6407898Z' and eventTimestamp le '2019-09-01T04:36:37.6407898Z'". And I have $request="xxxxx/values?api-version=2015-04-01&$filter={$filter}". I executed this line of code --> Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $request -Method Get -Headers $authHeader -ContentType "application/json", and received error message --> "Invoke-RestMethod : {"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"The filter criteria is not specified."}"

Comment: Well, to be precise you should have $request="xxxxx/values?api-version=2015-04-01&`$filter={$filter}"  i.e., have a backquote just before "$filter" so that its not considered as variable. Also another update is, have final Invoke-RestMethod  in a variable i.e., "$Output = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $request -Method Get -Headers $authHeader" and then have next line as "$Output.Value". This is because all your required Activity logs gets stored in note property named "value" in this case. I have updated initial answer with these slight and important changes for easy reference.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, works fine!! but last thing, I am receiving bunch of object properties, as I mentioned I need "PrincipalID", this property is nested under property "properties", how can I get this "PrincipalID", I tried to use select-object - expandproperty, but didnt get expected result. below extract from script output, Property "properties": "@{statusCode=OK; serviceRequestId=xxxx; responseBody={"properties":"principalId":"xxxx","principalType":"User","scope":"/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/Powershell/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxx","createdOn":"xxx"

Comment: Glad that it worked for you!! :) You can develop the script in different possible ways. One sample way is shown in "UPDATE2" section in the answer. I went with approach mentioned in "UPDATE2" section of the answer (leveraging 'split', 'like', etc.) because there is no specific note property or any other specific member under "responseBody" using which we can get the "principalId" directly.

Comment: I created a script, works as expected. Thank You for Your support, all Your comments were very useful! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi @KrishnaG-MSFT: I am using the same script as you mentioned and using the filter $filter="eventTimestamp ge '2019-10-16T04:36:37.6407898Z' and eventTimestamp le '2019-10-017T04:36:37.6407898Z'" but getting this error: Invoke-RestMethod : {"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"The filter property: {eventTimestamp is not supported."}. Any idea what could be reason?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
Get-AzureRmLog -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) | 
Where-Object {$_.Authorization.Action -like 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/*'} | 
Select-Object @{N="Caller";E={$_.Caller}}, 
@{N="Resource";E={$_.Authorization.Scope}}, 
@{N="Action";E={Split-Path $_.Authorization.action -leaf}},
@{N="Name";E={$_.Claims.Content.name}}, 
EventTimestamp
```

My output:

```
Caller         : username@domain.com
Resource       : /subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/xxxx
Action         : write
Name           : John Doe
EventTimestamp : 30.08.2019 12.05.52
```

NB: I used Get-AzLog. Not sure if there is any difference between Get-AzLog and Get-AzureRmLog.

Comment: Hi, Not exactly, under property Name: John Doe, we can see name o a user who performed tha change, Name = Caller, I need name of a user who has been granted permissions/assignment to the resource. For example if I add user1 to the rbac role in Access control AIM blade, next (role assignment), in the script output i need his name, user1.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly certain this wouldn't be exposed with this cmdlet. I dont even see this information in the Role Assignments. So not sure what do you mean exactly.

Comment: You can see this info in: Subscription --> Audit Log --> Create filter for Operation, type "role assignment" choose all three checkboxes, type "role definition" choose three checkboxes, change "Timespan" filter to last month. Then pickup event with description like "Create role assignment", and in the summary tab You will see item "Shared with", and I need this username using powershell.

Comment: right, so you'd have to do the same, but this makes no sense, because the assignment operation could have happened ages ago

Comment: According to this --> "but this makes no sense, because the assignment operation could have happened ages ago" - I need to catch changes made on azure resources, like new users assignment, so the solution make sense. For example new assignment will be created 1st of Sept, script will be executed on 2nd of Sept and in the out put You will see who made a change, on which resource, when etc...